# How to discard overlapping rectangles in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I used the `openCV` library to detect an object of the image (Fig 1), see below. [image: Fig 1]

To do this, I have written the following codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 

# source data
img_file= "Fig1.jpg"

# create an OpenCV image
img= cv2.imread(img_file)

# convert color image to grey image
gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

im_gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (5, 5), 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gauss, 127, 255, 0)
# get contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

margin = 40
# calculate area and filter 
for con in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(con)
    if 100 < area < 500:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(con)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x-margin, y-margin), (x + w+margin, y + h+margin), (0,255,0), 2)
        
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

These codes will able to give you an image with the detected object see below figure [image: Fig 2].

Now here you can see, while detecting objects, some rectangles are overlapping. This is not the expected outcome. I want a Figure which discards all overlap rectangles and comes with another figure that includes only those rectangle which is not overlapping. Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to post a result image that you want your output to look like. It is not exactly clear how you want your ROIs to be purged.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want a figure which exclude all the overlapping rectangle.

Comment: So, basically all those are false positives and none of them have any ROI? In that case @HansHirse's solution is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `x`, `y`, width, and height for each rectangle, you'll need pairwise comparisons for each two rectangles, checking for overlaps by comparing if

- `x` of rectangle #1 is between `x` and `x` + width of rectangle #2, or
- `y` of rectangle #1 is between `y` and `y` + height of rectangle #2, or
- ...

Fortunately, you can use NumPy's vectorization abilities to avoid nested loops.

In the following code, I generate some random rectangles, and filter out those overlapping:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Randomly generate n white rectangles on black background
n = 20
rects = [[np.random.randint(0, 350),
          np.random.randint(0, 250),
          np.random.randint(10, 50),
          np.random.randint(10, 50)] for i in range(n)]

img = np.zeros((300, 400), np.uint8)

for rect in rects:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (rect[0], rect[1]),
                        (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), 255, 1)

# Calculate left, right, top, bottom limits
rects = np.array(rects)
left = np.expand_dims(rects[:, 0], axis=1)
right = np.expand_dims(rects[:, 0] + rects[:, 2], axis=1)
top = np.expand_dims(rects[:, 1], axis=1)
bottom = np.expand_dims(rects[:, 1] + rects[:, 3], axis=1)

# Check for left limit intrusions, right limit intrusions, ...
check_l = (left <= left.T) & (left.T <= right)
check_r = (left <= right.T) & (right.T <= right)
check_t = (top <= top.T) & (top.T <= bottom)
check_b = (top <= bottom.T) & (bottom.T <= bottom)

# Check for combinations of left-top intrusions, left-bottom intrusions, ...
check_lt = check_l & check_t
check_lb = check_l & check_b
check_rt = check_r & check_t
check_rb = check_r & check_b

# Get all combinations; get rid of self identical matches
check = check_lt | check_lb | check_rt | check_rb
check = np.bitwise_xor(check, np.eye(n).astype(bool))
check = np.argwhere(check)

# Get unique indices of corrupted rectangles
corrupted = np.unique(check)

# Draw cleaned image
img_clean = np.zeros_like(img)
for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
    if i not in corrupted:
        img_clean = cv2.rectangle(img_clean, (rect[0], rect[1]),
                                  (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), 255, 1)

# Output
cv2.imshow('Original image', img)
cv2.imshow('Cleaned image', img_clean)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

First, let's have a look at the "input" and "output":

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Basically, the left, right, top, and bottom limit of each rectangle is computed. Then, each combination of rectangle #1 "intrudes" into rectangle #2 from the left, or from the top, or from the right, and so on, is calculated.

Several `bool` matrices of size `(n, n)`, with `n` is the number of rectangles,
are stored intermediately, but I guess, for `n <= 2000` or so, the memory consumption should be negligible. Due to the vectorization, this approach is quite fast.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I added the original figure and also added an excel file that shows the coordinates of the rectangle. Label: MN indicates red rectangle coordinates while the rest indicate green rectangle coordinates. Can you tell me how I can use ur code using this information to get my desired results?

Comment: Somehow I do not have the option to upload an excel file here. Nevertheless, I have x, y, width, and height for all my rectangle in an excel file. So basically, I have to use ur codes starting from # Check for left limit intrusions, right limit intrusions?

Comment: No, you'd need to start at `# Calculate left, right, top, bottom limits`, since `right` and `bottom` are calculated from `x`, `y`, width and height.

Comment: I am having difficulty implementing this code for a given image. Let say, if u gave this image as input then how can I use ur code.

Comment: What is 'rects' in case of my image?

Comment: Could you please add your existing code to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66868093/edit) it accordingly? It doesn't make much sense discussing code without seeing it.

Comment: I modified the question and added codes with the result. Please do have a look and help me.

Comment: In your loop, instead using `cv2.rectangle(...)` there, save `x`, `y`, `w`, `h` in some (nested) list, like I did it with `rects` in my code. Then, everything from `# Calculate left, right, top, bottom limits` should be applicable without any change.