# Calculating averge intensity via histogram plot

Tags: python, histogram, image-segmentation, opencv

I have code that used to detect the object of the image [code link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868093/how-to-discard-overlapping-rectangles-in-an-image) with a rectangle bound.

This will give the output image as shown below

[image]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COObp.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COObp.png)

Now I would like to calculate the average intensity of the green rectangle box and plot them against a number of green rectangle box. In short, plot the histogram of average intensity of all rectangle region. So far I have written the following codes for the histogram plot:

```
  from skimage import io
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    img = cv.imread('Fig1.png',0)
    
    bins = np.arange(250)
    ax = plt.hist(w4_img.ravel(), bins = bins)
    plt.xlabel('Pixel Values')
    plt.ylabel('No of Pixels')
    plt.show()
```

Which shows the distribution of intensity histogram but this does not show the histogram of the average intensity of all rectangle of Fig. Any idea how to do this in a more simpler way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the bounding boxes that compute in a loop from the contours. Use the bounding box and Numpy to get a crop `crop=gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]`. Then use Numpy to get the average value for that box as `crop_ave=np.mean(crop)` and store in a list. Once you have the list, convert it to a Numpy array and get the average of that array.

Comment: But how to use this for plotting histogram? Any example with codes?

Comment: Once you have an array of crop_ave values, you can compute the histogram using cv2.calcHist(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d